# I want to flash an UIImageview on the iPad, how do I do that?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview

I want to let a `UIImageView` flash several times.

Currently I don't know how to do that.

#### Actual code:

```
-(void)arrowsAnimate{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        arrow1.alpha = 1.0;
        arrow2.alpha = 1.0;
        arrow3.alpha = 1.0;
        NSLog(@"alpha 1");
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){        

        [self arrowsAnimate2];
                    
    }];
}

-(void)arrowsAnimate2{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
         arrow1.alpha = 0.0;
         arrow2.alpha = 0.0;
         arrow3.alpha = 0.0;
         NSLog(@"alpha 0");
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){;}];
}
```

later on I call it like this:

```
for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++){
[self arrowsAnimate]; }
```

This gives me 10x alpha 1, and then 10x alpha 0. In the middle we see only one animation.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a simpler way to achieve a flashing animation using only 1 animation block:

```
aview.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^ {
       [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10.0f/2.0f];
       aview.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
       [aview removeFromSuperview]; 
}];
```

The trick is to use `[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:NTIMES/2]; *_inside_* your animation block`. 
No need for extra functions or extra loops.

Comment: Whoa, didn't notice you can use some of the old animation functions in block animations. This works and is correct as per the documentation.

Comment: For those who want to have it only flash once - get rid of the [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10.0f/2.0f]; - and instead, just put the alpha back to 1.0f in the completion block.

Answer (score 3):

Use

`+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`

and pass the `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` and probably `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` in your options. You shouldn't need to provide a completion block and only perform the first animation.

Edit: here is some sample code for an image that fades in and out indefinitely.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse) 
                 animations:^{
                     self.myImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Edit 2: I see you actually need to flash it 10 times only. I wasn't able to do that with blocks actually. When the completion block executed, the animation seemed to complete instantly the remaining 9 times. I was however able to do this with just the old-style animations quite easily.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

self.myImageView.alpha = 1.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Edit 3: I found a way to do this with blocks.

```
- (void)animate
{
    if (self.animationCount < 10)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                         animations:^{
                             self.myImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self animateBack];
                         }];
    }
}

- (void)animateBack
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         self.myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.animationCount++;
                         [self animate];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: that does sound lovely, but I failed to do this, could you pleas tell me how to implement this?

Comment: I just updated my answer. I was able to get it to go indefinitely with blocks, but not stop after 10 times. I have, however, been able to do it without blocks and provided code to do that. Also, @Bogatyr is correct, you're not going to be able to call 10 animations in a row and have them stack up nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any point not to use the old-style animations? The only thing I know, is that one _should_ not use those, but is anything else affected? If not, there would not be anything holding me back taking the old-style animations! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've never heard anything to not use them, but I've been having to do a lot of backward-compatible apps lately so maybe I'm not clued in. As far as I know they are not deprecated so I see no reason to not do them if that helps you. Edit: Apple's docs say "use is discouraged on OS 4.0" but has no clear reason why this is so and they aren't marked as deprecated.

Comment: I went back and figured out how to do it using blocks and edited my answer. HOpefully this helps.

Comment: I am impressed. Thank you! By the way: "Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. If you are using the block-based animation methods, you can include your delegate’s end code directly inside your block. " Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816

Answer (score 1):

Above blinking may not work when your app go background and foreground at time of blinking.
Instead of these you can take a transparent image and your actual image and animate your ImageView

```
UIImageView *imageview=[UIImageView new];
imageview.animationDuration=1;
imageview.animationImages = your array of images;
[imageview startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for an animation to complete before launching a new one.  You could chain your completion block in animate2 to go back to animate, and stop based on a counter property, implementing your loop in the animate/completion blocks instead of a separate loop.

Comment: Can you tell me why there should be a diffrence? What does implementing the counter inside the blocks change?

Comment: It seems to me you're running the animations simultaneously and there interfering with each other, at the very least they're all doing their work in parallel instead of one after the other.  Thus you only see "one" animation.   You need to make sure one animation runs and finishes before launching the second animation, and so on.

Comment: It seems to me from the NSLog output, that first the 10 animations run with alpha = 1, and then the animations with alpha = 0, making only one transition. I'll look into it.