# Make UIImageView Flash - Animation Block

Tags: xcode, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to make a `UIImageView` flash a few times when it collides with another in a small game I'm making.

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043897/i-want-to-flash-an-uiimageview-on-the-ipad-how-do-i-do-that) answer on this exchange and the answer that's been accepted as the best is this:

```
MyImage.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f                     //speed of flash
                      delay:0.0f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^ {
       [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4.0f/2.0f];   //flash few times
       MyImage.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
       [MyImage removeFromSuperview]; 
}];
```

I also like edit 3's code on the 2nd answer down. However the above is the one I've been working with.

It works great but I'm having trouble having my `UIImageView` returning back to normal, after the flash has happened...

I've tried reseting the alpha value back to `1.0f` in the completion block, and even at the end of the method I call to start the animation, but whatever I seem to be trying leaves the image invisible after the flashes... What am I missing? Thank you.

**EDIT**
I've also tried this way, and the image fades out and comes back, but it will only do it once :( I would like it to do it a few times:

```
    -(void)AnimateComboFlash{        //call when collision occurs
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            [self AltFlash];
        }
    }

    -(void)AltFlash{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        MyImage.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self AltFlashBack];
    }

    -(void)AltFlashBack{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        MyImage.alpha = 1.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyImage.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f                     //speed of flash
                      delay:0.0f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^ {
   [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4.0f/2.0f];   //flash few times
   MyImage.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
    if (finished) {
       [MyImage removeFromSuperview]; 
    }
}];
```

You need to check if the animation is finished before you set the final value.

Answer (score 0):

So after a long time reading through various questions and answers on this exchange about `UIImageView` animations, I finally found an answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368397/uibutton-flashing-animation), by `Enceradeira` that worked for me, allowing the flash animation to happen, then the image to return to "normal" (with a full 1.0 alpha value).

Using his answer, and the code in my question, this is the method I used to make my `UIImageView` flash a few times, then return to it's original state:

```
MyImage.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f                     //speed of flash
                      delay:0.0f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^ {
       [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4.0f/2.0f];   //flash few times
       MyImage.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
      //[MyImage removeFromSuperview];               //REMOVE THE REMOVE
      MyImage.alpha = 1.0f;                          //RESET ALPHA VALUE AFTER COMPLETION
}];
```

Hopefully this will help some of you looking for similar answers.